# Designable Button does not show images from assets folder

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I customized a button and I wanted to make it designable in the storyboard.
If I set the background to an image which is stored in the assets folder, the storyboard doesn't show anything. I still get a transparent button. Any ideas how i can fix this?

```swift
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class AnswerButton: UIButton {
    
    private static let BTN_NORMAL_IMAGE_NAME = "ButtonNormal"
    private static let BTN_ANSWERED_IMAGE_NAME = "ButtonAnswered"

    
    enum AnswerState : Int {
        case normal = 0
        case answered
        case correctAnswered
        case wrongAnswered
    }
    
    var answerState: AnswerState = .normal {
        didSet {
            if answerState == .normal {
                self.answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
                self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: AnswerButton.BTN_NORMAL_IMAGE_NAME), for: .normal)
            } else if answerState == .answered {
                self.answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: AnswerButton.BTN_ANSWERED_IMAGE_NAME), for: .normal)
            } else if answerState == .correctAnswered {
                self.answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
                self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: AnswerButton.BTN_ANSWERED_IMAGE_NAME), for: .normal)
            }
        
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var myAnswerState: Int {
        get {
            return self.answerState.rawValue
        }
        set (value) {
            self.setAnswerState(AnswerState(rawValue: value) ?? .normal)
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBInspectable var letter: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.letterLabel.text = String(letter.first!) + ":"
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var answer: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.answerLabel.text = answer
        }
    }
    
    public let letterLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.textColor = UIColor.orange
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 24)
        
        return label
    }()

    public let answerLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 22)
        
        return label
    }()
    
        
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        self.letterLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: 30, height: self.frame.height)
        self.answerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 0, width: 310, height: self.frame.height)
    }
    
    
    private func setAnswerState(_ state: AnswerState) {
        self.answerState = state
    }
    
    private func setLetter(_ letter: String) {
        self.letter = letter
    }
    
    private func setAnswer(_ answer: String) {
        self.answer = answer
    }
    
    init(letter: String, selectionState: AnswerState, answer: String) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 420, height: 47))
        self.sharedInit()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.sharedInit()
    }
    
    @objc
    func touchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
        self.setAnswerState(.answered)
    }
    
    func sharedInit() {
        self.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        self.setLetter(letter)
        self.setAnswer(answer)
        self.setAnswerState(.normal)
        
        self.addSubview(self.letterLabel)
        self.addSubview(self.answerLabel)
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        self.sharedInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.sharedInit()
    }
}
```

an image with the name ButtonBackground lives in the assets folder.

Comment: Please add some code. How you setup this?

Comment: A `UIButton` already has a Background Image property that can be set in Storyboard, so it's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish. Edit your post with a *clear* description of what you're doing, and include the full code from your `@IBDesignable` subclassed button.

Comment: i know that it has a background image, but i want to set it by code. So i want to give the button a state and the state handles the background image.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues in your code...

First, to get images to load at design-time / `@IBDesignable`, you need to tell Interface Builder where to get them:

```
let dynamicBundle = Bundle(for: AnswerButton.self)
let img = UIImage(named: AnswerButton.BTN_NORMAL_IMAGE_NAME, in: dynamicBundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

Unless you're doing something out-of-the-ordinary with your bundle structures, you can use that both at design-time and run-time. That is, you don't conditional code.

Next, in your `@IBInspectable var letter / didSet`:

```
@IBInspectable var letter: String = "" {
    didSet {
        self.letterLabel.text = String(letter.first!) + ":"
    }
}
```

make sure your string is not empty or it will crash:

```
@IBInspectable var letter: String = "" {
    didSet {
        if !letter.isEmpty {
            self.letterLabel.text = String(letter.first!) + ":"
        }
    }
}
```

Next, your `sharedInit()` func will be called when you change an `@IBInspectable` value, so don't call this:

```
self.setAnswerState(.normal)
```

or your button will never reflect any other value.

And, the way you're setting frames for your labels looks problematic -- if the button width is less than 390-pts, the `answerLabel` won't fit.

Lastly, I'd suggest loading your two images at init, instead of re-loading every time the state changes.

Here's an update to your class:

```
@IBDesignable class AnswerButton: UIButton {
    
    private static let BTN_NORMAL_IMAGE_NAME = "ButtonNormal"
    private static let BTN_ANSWERED_IMAGE_NAME = "ButtonAnswered"
    
    private var normalImage: UIImage!
    private var answeredImage: UIImage!

    enum AnswerState : Int {
        case normal
        case answered
        case correctAnswered
        case wrongAnswered
    }
    
    var answerState: AnswerState = .normal {
        didSet {
            switch answerState {
            case .answered:
                self.answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                self.setBackgroundImage(answeredImage, for: .normal)

            case .correctAnswered:
                self.answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue
                self.setBackgroundImage(answeredImage, for: .normal)
                
            case .wrongAnswered:
                self.answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                self.setBackgroundImage(answeredImage, for: .normal)
                
            default:
                self.answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
                self.setBackgroundImage(normalImage, for: .normal)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var myAnswerState: Int {
        get {
            return self.answerState.rawValue
        }
        set (value) {
            if let t: AnswerState = AnswerState(rawValue: value) {
                self.setAnswerState(t)
            } else {
                self.setAnswerState(.normal)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBInspectable var letter: String = "" {
        didSet {
            if !letter.isEmpty {
                self.letterLabel.text = String(letter.first!) + ":"
            }
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var answer: String = "" {
        didSet {
            self.answerLabel.text = answer
        }
    }
    
    public let letterLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.textColor = UIColor.orange
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 24)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
        return label
    }()
    
    public let answerLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 22)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
        return label
    }()
    
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        self.letterLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 0, width: 30, height: self.frame.height)
        self.answerLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 0, width: 310, height: self.frame.height)
    }
    
    
    private func setAnswerState(_ state: AnswerState) {
        self.answerState = state
    }
    
    private func setLetter(_ letter: String) {
        self.letter = letter
    }
    
    private func setAnswer(_ answer: String) {
        self.answer = answer
    }
    
    init(letter: String, selectionState: AnswerState, answer: String) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 420, height: 47))
        setAnswer(answer)
        self.sharedInit()
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.sharedInit()
    }
    
    @objc
    func touchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
        self.setAnswerState(.answered)
    }
    
    func sharedInit() {
        self.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUpInside), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        self.setLetter(letter)
        self.setAnswer(answer)
        
        // don't call this here!
        //self.setAnswerState(.normal)

        self.addSubview(self.letterLabel)
        self.addSubview(self.answerLabel)
        
        // load normal / answered images once
        let dynamicBundle = Bundle(for: AnswerButton.self)

        if let img = UIImage(named: AnswerButton.BTN_NORMAL_IMAGE_NAME, in: dynamicBundle, compatibleWith: nil) {
            self.normalImage = img
        }
        if let img = UIImage(named: AnswerButton.BTN_ANSWERED_IMAGE_NAME, in: dynamicBundle, compatibleWith: nil) {
            self.answeredImage = img
        }
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.sharedInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.sharedInit()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u so much. There was still a lot of testing code init, but u solved my problem. I tried it once with the dynamic bundle, but it didn't work. Now it works. Im developing a game especially for the ipad pro 10.5. So i keep it simple and put a lot of hardcoded sizes in it.